# How i can order like a index book in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with VueJS, I have an object array like this:

```
`const myarray = [
    {'secction': '6.2.3','title': 'a'},
    {'secction': '6.2.2','title': 'b'},
    {'secction': '11.3.1','title': 'bn'},
    {'secction': '10.5.1','title': 'z'},
    {'secction': '10.4.1', title: 'da'}
]`
```

I want to order like:

```
6.2.3
6.2.2
10.4.1
10.5.1
11.3.1
```

but I aplied this fuction:

```
myarray.sort( (a ,b) => {
    if (a.Control_num < b.Control_num) return -1
    if (a.Control_num > b.Control_num) return 1
        return 0
})
```

and the result is the following:

```
10.4.1
10.5.1
10.6.2 
11.2.2
11.3.1
6.2.2
6.2.3
```

Comment: What is `a.Control_num`?

Comment: I hope you want `6.2.2` before `6.2.3`

Comment: the Control_num  is = secction

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is the split the sections and make that into a number you can sort on..

eg.  6.2.3 -> 60203    10.5.1 -> 105010  etc.

The sort is then just a simple matter of subtract one from the other..

example...

```js
const myarray = [
    {'secction': '6.2.3','title': 'a'},
    {'secction': '6.2.2','title': 'b'},
    {'secction': '11.3.1','title': 'bn'},
    {'secction': '10.5.1','title': 'z'},
    {'secction': '10.4.1', title: 'da'}
];


function num(a) {
  var b = a.secction.split(".");
  return b[0] * 10000 + b[1] * 100  + b[2];
}

myarray.sort((a,b) => {
  return num(a) - num(b);
});

myarray.forEach((a) => console.log(a.secction + ' -> ' + a.title));
```

Comment: Hey Keith, I don't think this works. Suppose for example one of the inputs is: {'secction': '6.2222222222.2','title': 'b'}

Comment: @Cam  it will of course work up with sections up 99,.. But if you ever find a book with sections greater than this, you could of course multiple by bigger numbers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The aim is to check first the left part of the number, then the middle part, and the right part at the end.

- If a1 > b1, then return sth >= 1
- If a1 < b1, return sth <= -1
- But if a1 = a2, then check a2 and b2 (and apply this same process again, till a3 and b3)

```js
const myarray = [
  {'secction': '6.2.3','title': 'a'},
  {'secction': '6.2.2','title': 'b'},
  {'secction': '11.3.1','title': 'bn'},
  {'secction': '10.5.1','title': 'z'},
  {'secction': '10.4.1', title: 'da'}
]

function bySecction(a, b) {
  const [a1, a2, a3] = a.secction.split('.')
  const [b1, b2, b3] = b.secction.split('.')
  
  return (a1 - b1) && (a2 - b2) && (a3 - b3)
}

myarray
  .sort(bySecction)
  .reverse()

console.log(myarray)
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. Suppose one of the inputs is '6.99999.2', for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort like this

```js
const myarray = [
    {'secction': '6.2.3','title': 'a'},
    {'secction': '6.2.2','title': 'b'},
    {'secction': '11.3.1','title': 'bn'},
    {'secction': '10.5.1','title': 'z'},
    {'secction': '10.4.1', title: 'da'}
];

const result = myarray.sort((a, b) => {
  const n1 = a.secction.split('.').reverse().map((n, index) => n * (10^index)).reduce((i, j) => i + j, 0);
  const n2 = b.secction.split('.').reverse().map((n, index) => n * (10^index)).reduce((i, j) => i + j, 0);
  
  return n1 - n2;
});

console.log(result);
```